# Detect when input is start/end focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

I need to know if it's possible to detect when is input start focused and when is focus ended

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="datas" >
<input type="text" value="" class="datas" >
<input type="text" value="" class="datas" >
```

JQuery code(only example how i need this):

```
$('.datas').on('focusStart', alert("focusStarted"));
$('.datas').on('focusEnd', alert("focusEnded"));
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks for it.

**Answer:**

JQuery code:

```
$(".datas").focus(function(){
    alert("This input field has starts focus.");
});
$(".datas").blur(function(){
    alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
});
```

Comment: You are either looking for onfocus / onblur or selectStart / selectEnd

Comment: focus and blur should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('.datas').on('focus',function(){
        alert('focusStarted');
    }).on('blur',function(){
        alert('focusEnded');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess "focus" and "blur" are what events you are looking for.

```
$('.datas').on('focus', alert("focusStarted"));
$('.datas').on('blur', alert("focusEnded"));
```

Hope that help.